# Media Queries in jQuery not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Кто может подсказать почему этот код не срабатывает? Точнее медиа запрос через `js` не срабатывает, функция отрабатывает при любой ширине монитора

checkMedia();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    checkMedia();
});

function checkMedia() {

    var headerCart = $('.header__cart');

    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)').matches) {

        headerCart.mouseenter(function(){
            $('.header__cart > .title').fadeOut(0);
            $('.header__cart > .img').fadeOut(0);
            $('.header__cart > .sum').fadeOut(0);
            $('.header__cart > .content').fadeIn(200);
            $('.header__cart > .button').fadeIn(0);
        });

        headerCart.mouseleave(function(){
            $('.header__cart > .content').fadeOut(0);
            $('.header__cart > .button').fadeOut(0);
            $('.header__cart > .title').fadeIn(200);
            $('.header__cart > .img').fadeIn(200);
            $('.header__cart > .sum').fadeIn(200);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `if($(window).width() < 992) {`

Answer (score 1):

Медиа запрос работает, скорее всего вы что-то не так делаете с `headerCart (mouseenter и mouseleave)`. В примере и по скрину можно увидеть что все работает

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  checkMedia();
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  checkMedia();
});

function checkMedia() {

  console.log('work')

  var headerCart = $('.header__cart');

  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)').matches) {

    console.log('work max-width: 992px')

    headerCart.mouseenter(function() {
      $('.header__cart > .title').fadeOut(0);
      $('.header__cart > .img').fadeOut(0);
      $('.header__cart > .sum').fadeOut(0);
      $('.header__cart > .content').fadeIn(200);
      $('.header__cart > .button').fadeIn(0);
    });

    headerCart.mouseleave(function() {
      $('.header__cart > .content').fadeOut(0);
      $('.header__cart > .button').fadeOut(0);
      $('.header__cart > .title').fadeIn(200);
      $('.header__cart > .img').fadeIn(200);
      $('.header__cart > .sum').fadeIn(200);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]